# Use recycleView views outside the recycle class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to use recycleView view out side it ?

I mean, in my viewHolder, Here is my full adapter :

```
    public MyAdapter(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, List<String> list) {
            this.listItem = listItem;
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Log.d(logTag, "view group " + parent);
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_row, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(new File(list.get(position)))
                    // .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.imageView);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            initiateView.passMyProgressBar(holder.progressBar);
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + list);
            holder.imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    alertView("Are you sure you want to remove this image?" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;
                }
            });
            holder.uploaded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });

            //uploadImage(bitmap, position, holder.progressBar, holder.imageView, holder.uploaded, list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }


        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private ImageView imageView, uploaded;
            private ProgressBar progressBar;


            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRow);
                progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                uploaded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uploadedImg);
            }
        }

//        public void setOnItemClickListener(final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
//            this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
//        }

        public void removeAt(int position) {
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
        }
    }
```

can i use them in outer class like :

```
ProgressBar progressBar = recycleViewLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setVisiblity(VISIBLE);
```

if not, can i create listener or something, I know it's not good way, but webservices forced me to do that.

Comment: @Enzokie Indeed you are right, that's anti pattern, but web services forced me to do that.

Comment: Can you also add your Full adapter code?

Comment: @Enzokie updated

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an interface within your Adapter to achieve this. It could be like this -

```
public interface MyDelegate {
    void passMyProgressBar (ProgressBar pBar);
}
```

Instantiate it and then at `onBindViewHolder`, add this line -

```
myDelegateInstance.passMyProgressBar(holder.progressBar);
```

Now, you must implement the above interface in the class where you want your ProgressBar accessable.

Comment: what after implement? i implemented it but i can't control the progressbar

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to hide progressBar after i upload images in other class.